# PHP Date Format Confusion

Tags: php, date, format

I have this date in my database `11/06/2013 12:00`

This is my code and the format I would like it in

```
$dateformatstart = date_format(date_create($row['datestart']), 'D j M y H:i');
```

Although it comes back as

`Wed 6 Nov 13 12:00`

Think the month is the day and day is the month, I don't know why

Thanks

Comment: What would you like your date to look like? You didn't state that.

Comment: @TommyNaidich I need it in this format: D j M y H:i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $row['datestart']);

$dateformatstart = date_format($date, 'D j M y H:i');
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you even checked out the **[php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)** before asking this question?

Well, Here are some clever ways on how to format dates in PHP

```
<?php
// Assuming today is March 10th, 2001, 5:16:18 pm, and that we are in the
// Mountain Standard Time (MST) Time Zone

$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
$today = date("Y/m/d H:i");                   // 2001-03-10 17:16:18 (the MySQL DATETIME format)
```

If you are trying to output a data format like this :

`11/06/2013 12:00`

then better,  Use

`$today = date("d/m/Y H:i");`